# akka-io 2.3.x how to decode frame

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I read through the documentation, and found nothing related. The `2.2.x` doc page http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/scala/io-codec.html page not available for 2.3.x.

Where can I find related resources

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html#Experimental_Pipelines_IO_abstraction_has_been_removed

Comment: @ViktorKlang I have to manipulate the `bytestring` myself ?

Comment: Either that, or use the known discontinued Pipelines feature, or wait until the replacement is available.

Comment: @ViktorKlang The pipeline are removed. If I want to use that, shall I bring `spray-io` ?

Comment: If you MUST use 2.3 AND Pipelines (even though they are removed) just add the 2 files from the 2.2 release to your project and maintain them there. Or you use 2.2 or wait for the replacement. Keep in mind that experimental features are not advised to use in a production environment and may be changed or removed without deprecation.